# Select column names by importance

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe, selection

I have a dataframe with 6 columns and float values in it. So I need select for each row top 3 colnames (delimited by space) with highest values in it at each row. For example with

```
rowIndex col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 
       1  0.2  0.4  0.1  1.2  2.2  0.2
       2  4.1  2.3  0.1  2.2  0.2  0.2
```

the result shold look like:

```
rowIndex importances
       1  col5 col4 col2
       2  col1 col2 col3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nrows = 2
ncols = 6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nrows,ncols), index=list(range(nrows)), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])

print(df)

for row in range(nrows):
    maxCol1, maxCol2, maxCol3 = 0, 0, 0
    for col in range(ncols):
        if(df.iloc[row, col] > df.iloc[row, maxCol1]):
            maxCol3 = maxCol2
            maxCol2 = maxCol1
            maxCol1 = col
        elif(df.iloc[row, col] > df.iloc[row, maxCol2]):
            maxCol3 = maxCol2
            maxCol2 = col
        elif(df.iloc[row, col] > df.iloc[row, maxCol3]):
            maxCol3 = col
    print("{} {} {} {}".format(row+1, df.columns[maxCol1], df.columns[maxCol2], df.columns[maxCol3]))
```

Would produce a result like:

```
   col1      col2      col3      col4      col5      col6
0  0.116408  0.316982  0.811001  0.964968  0.019989  0.674887
1  0.241690  0.429653  0.456779  0.398780  0.861042  0.149223
1 col4 col3 col6
2 col5 col3 col2
```